# How to write path in pom.xml maven file for unix based system

Tags: maven, unix, path, pom.xml

I am following a maven tutorial and the tutor is using windows while am using linux in his example theres a line in the pom.xml as such

```
<files.repository.name>C:\\Sigmah\\files\\sigmah_dev</files.repository.name>
```

For me on ubuntu I have the same files in this  directory ~/sigmah/files/sigmah_dev

So I modified the pom.xml file as such

```
<files.repository.name>~/sigmah/files/sigmah_dev</files.repository.name>
```

But I still get a maven error complaining this directory does not exist. Please what am I doing wrong

Comment: Can you do `echo $HOME` once and paste the output here?

Comment: This is the output "/home/fenn"

Comment: `~` is shell syntax that expands to your home directory. maven most likely won't know how to expand it. You'd be best to stick to the full path, something like `/home/fenn/sigmah/files/...`

Comment: You should never use a path to a repository....Use the defaults...So in the end no need to configure such things in a pom file. If this is written in a turtorial this tutorial is not really a good tutorial.

Comment: Please I don't understand what you mean @khmarbaise

Comment: Can you say what this location is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `pom.xml` to to reflect the same path is in `$HOME` environment variable which has your absolute home directory path.

```
<files.repository.name>/home/fenn/sigmah/files/sigmah_dev</files.repository.name>
```

Comment: Thnks for your efforts!